# Error when creating Synonym in SQL Server 2016 with the same table name

Tags: sql-server, synonym

We have a synonym created for the DB that is year specific i.e DST2016. I want to create synonym for the database for the 2017 year i.e DST2017, so that all our jobs point to the year 2017 automatically.

When I run the command
`create synonym ABS for [DST2017].[dbo].[ABS]`
 I get the following error:

> There is already an object named 'ABS' in the database.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: Drop the 2016 synonym first?

Comment: @james z I tried that. worked fine. But have a new issue now. The DB where I created the synonym is CURRENTDB. it does not allow me to USE [CURRENTDB] , getting error ** Database 'CURRENTDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.**

Comment: Drop that one and create it in the correct db? Check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/create-synonyms) for the syntax.

Comment: Are you doing this for more than one table?

Comment: @chuck yes for all tables in the DST2017 database

Comment: In my jobs I have USE [CURRENTDB]  where all the synonyms exist for the current year database DST2017  tables.

Comment: Thank you, Everyone. I did the whole thing once again with USE [CURRENTDB] command before dropping all the synonyms and then same for creating synonyms. It worked flawlessly.  Thanks once again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have created the old ones (synonym), but maybe you could do something like this to remove the old ones:

```
select 'drop  synonym ' + name 
from sys.tables order by name
```

Then use this command to create the new ones:

```
declare @db as varchar(50) = (select db_name())
select 'create synonym ' + name + ' for ' + @db + '.dbo.' + name 
from sys.tables order by name
```

You also need to be in a different database that the tables are in, otherwise you will get the error above.

Comment: A new issue we encountered this morning. The jobs that are using this DB and have command like USE CURRENTDB; do not run and give error. Why is it expecting the parenthesis [] around CURRENTDB ? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Database 'CURRENTDB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: A liitle bit more info that might help. When I run 
`select *
from sys.databases
where name = 'CURRENTDB'' I donot get any record, but when I run without the 'where' clause I see it in the list. There seems to be a hidden character in the name. I am trying renaming the DB Name.